# Android Listview with Button get Item position

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview with a button in it. is there any possible way to check which button was clicked and in which position of the listview ?

[image]

here is my code.

```
    final RelativeLayout layoutFooter2 = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.foodlist, null);
    final Button btnBack = (Button) layoutFooter2.findViewById(R.id.Back);
    // buttonadd
    final Button btnadd = (Button) layoutFooter2.findViewById(R.id.btnaddd);
    // buttondelete
    final ListView listView = getListView();
    final TextView txvSum = (TextView) layoutFooter.findViewById(R.id.Sum);
    txvSum.setText("");
    listView.invalidateViews();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.addFooterView(layoutFooter);
    listView.setAdapter(getListAdapter());
    // changes have been done here in order to fit the buttons in textview55+ changes to large/foodlist.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, R.layout.foodlist, R.id.textview55, ListItemSalads));
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityFoodsSalads.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

xml file

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/kati" 
        > 

    <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview55" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/listviewborder"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:padding="12dp"
  android:textSize="24sp" >
  </TextView>


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnaddd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="112dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="#3b3974"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#f1ecef" />
```

Any advice is much appriciated.Cheers.

Comment: one advice put the code what u tried

Comment: Add your adapter code and listview item/row xml to your question

Comment: ok i will do this now thanks guys.

Comment: Add `foodlist.xml` (the listview item/row xml)  too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a click listener in your Adapter's `getView` method

**NOTE:** since you did not post your foodlist.xml, please change "R.id.buttonId" to reference the ID value you set for the button's android:id attribute in your foodlist.xml

```
// changes have been done here in order to fit the buttons in textview55+ changes to large/foodlist.
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ListItemSalads>(this, R.layout.foodlist, R.id.textview55, ListItemSalads) {
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View inflatedView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // set a click listener 
        // TODO change "R.id.buttonId" to reference the ID value you set for the button's android:id attribute in foodlist.xml
        inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button 1  clicked for row position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return inflatedView;

    }
});
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
//btnadd.setOnClickListener is not needed anymore
```

Comment: Hey @Petey thanks for your posts, I have updated my question with the xml file. Let me try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove the buttons inside the `TextView` and use `ItemClickListener` to listen to clicks inside the `ListView`.

Try it as below

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.d("Item clicked..position: ",""+arg2);     
   }

});
```

Comment: Let me try this @Lal. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: what happens if i get to add two buttons though in each row of the listview? how will i know which one was clicked because there is only one textview @Lal.

Comment: I tried what you have said but the log happens when i click inside a row not on the button @Lal.

Comment: @Kristo as i mentioned in my answer, remove the buttons from the listview and just use the clicks on the items in the listview.

Comment: Could you check my xml please. I dont want to remove the buttons thats the point @Lal.

Answer (score 0):

In layout, set the onclick of the button are defined as onClickItemButton.

```
 public void onClickItemButton(View view) {
    View item = (View) view.getParent();
    int pos = listView.getPositionForView(item);
    long id = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set action for buttons. If,you set action listener for listview it cannot be get a selected position